# Javascript forgets this.something variable

Tags: javascript, object, this, intervals

I have in JavaScript class (function) with variable this.foo and function this.bar(), this.bar() I call in interval but have a small problem, JavaScript forgets this.foo and i cant use this.foo in this.bar(). Why?

```
function Somethink(element) {
    this.foo = element;

    this.bar = function () {
            // And now this.foo is undefined
    }

    setInterval(this.bar, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `this` is the window scope when the interval runs. You need to use a closure or `bind()`

```
window.setInterval(this.bar.bind(this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

It happens because setInterval calls this.bar in context of global object, not in the context of current object. Try to call it in this way:

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function () { self.bar() }, 1000);
```

**Update**
As it has been pointed in comments, another option is to use bind()

```
setInterval(this.bar.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: I would agree with @epascarello second option more. Much easier to just use `.bind`... `setInterval(self.bar.bind(this),1000);`

Comment: The "self" is not needed. this.bar.bind(this) would be enough

Comment: yeah, I didn't mean to put that there xD. I was just looking at the self in your post and typed it by accident. I meant `setInterval(this.bar.bind(this), 1000);`. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

```
function Somethink(element) {
    var foo = element;

    var bar = function () {

    }

setInterval(bar, 1000)
}
```

Use variables instead. 'This' changes context depending where you call it

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct. At the time when `bar()` is called, `this` might anything. The usual workaround is to assign `this` to a local variable:

```
function Somethink(element) {
    var that = this; // trick
    that.foo = element;

    that.bar = function () {
            // Use "that" in here
    }

    setInterval(that.bar, 1000)
}
```

`that` will make sure the code keeps a reference to the original value of `this`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this :

```
function Somethink(element) {
    this.foo = element;

    this.bar = function () {
        // And now this.foo is undefined
    }
    var self = this

    setInterval(self.bar, 1000)
 }
```

Comment: "self.bar" will be called in global object context anyway.